# A problem from George casella statistical inference on completeness.

Tags: statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

[image]

To check completeness I calculated $E(g(x))$ for first distribution and i get it in the polynomial form as

$p(g(0) + 3g(1)-4g(2)) + g(2)$

For Distribution $2$ i get 
$p^2(g(1)-g(2)) + p(g(0)-g(2)) + g(2)$

In all the questions of completeness we check if $E(g(x)) = 0$
What i thought in this question is that in both the cases if $g(0),g(1),g(2)=0$ i get $E(g(x))=0$  implies both distribution are complete. But i am getting wrong answers someone correct me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether "$E_p[g(X)]=0$ for all $p$" implies "$P_p(g(X)=0)=1$ for all $p$."

In the first case, show that "$E_p[g(X)]=0$ for all $p$" is equivalent to $g(0)+3g(1)=0$ and $g(2)=0$. However, this does not imply "$g(X)=0$ almost surely for any $p$"; take $g(0)=3$, $g(1)=-1$, and $g(2)=0$ for example.

In the second case, show that "$E_p[g(X)]=0$ for all $p$" is equivalent to $g(0)=g(1)=g(2)=0$, which does lead to "$g(X)=0$ almost surely for all $p$."

Comment: In first case if i take all the three g(x) individually zero?

Comment: @Daman I don't understand your question. If $g(0)=g(1)=g(2)=0$ then you will always have $E[g(X)]=0$ no matter what the distribution is. But this is not the definition of completeness; the implication is in the opposite direction.

Comment: I know right i didn't have definition in my mind sorry. I got it now tha ks.

Comment: One more question. So g(x) must be identically zero? taking some other values of g(x) makes it incomplete? Do you have any simple definition that fits in my mind i am still confused.

Comment: @Daman In plainer (but less precise) language, the family is complete if whenever you have $E[g(X)]=0$ for all distributions in the family, then you can conclude that $g$ is identically zero [almost surely]. For an incomplete family, there exists functions $g$ that are not identically zero, but still have $E[g(X)]=0$ for every distribution in the family.

Comment: I will now imply this in questions  do you have any idea from where should i get these type of questions ?